# click button (not in form) with mechanize/nokogiri

Tags: ruby, nokogiri, mechanize

I'd like to be able to click a single button (not in a form) with mechanize/nokogiri.

I just don't get how I could do this.

eg:

```
<button class="ui-FollowButton" type="button">
  <span class="buttonText">Folgen</span>
</button>
```

Hope somebody could help me! :)

Comment: You're expecting some kind of javascript event to get fired, but those will never happen with mechanize.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can probably use "watir" insteed. It can mimic the actions (such as clicking, rolling the page) in a browser.

Comment: I'm using watir now! :) Thank you sir!